# Join table on executeQuery AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How can I join the SalesQuotationLine, CustTable and CustTrans on SalesQuotationTable `executeQuery()` method?

I need to join multiple tables on SalesQuotationTable -> executeQuery() method for me to get the filtered data (data to be display must not exceed on credit limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to put the logic of calculating the total amount of a quotation into a single query, let alone comparing it and the open transaction amount (which also has to be calculated) against the credit limit of the customer.

Instead I propose the following solution: Dynamically add a temporary data source of table `TmpRecIdFilter` to the query, linked on field `RefRecId` to the `RecId` of the `SalesQuotationTable` datasource. Fill the `RefRecId` field with the `RecId` values of the `SalesQuotationTable` records that you want to filter. Without the constraint of a query it should be pretty straightforward to come up with a logic that can determine the `SalesQuotationTable` that do not exceed the credit limit.